# Electricity Bill tariff slab calculation using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, sum

I have table "Readings" with the following schema:

```
----------------------------------------
|  Id  |        DateTime     |  value  |
---------------------------------------
|  16  |  01/01/19  22:50:59 |    90   | 
---------------------------------------
|  16  |  01/02/19  8:53:11  |    200  | 
---------------------------------------
|  16  |  04/01/19  22:50:59 |    400  |  
---------------------------------------
|  16  |  03/01/19  1:20:00  |    100  |
---------------------------------------
```

And Another table "Tariffs" with the following schema:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  Id  |   start_value  | end_value |    rate   |
-------------------------------------------------
|  16  |        0       |    100    |    0.2    | 
-------------------------------------------------
|  16  |       100      |    500    |    0.25   | 
------------------------------------------------
|  16  |       500      |    1000   |    0.3    |   
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the total cost as the example here:
The summation of values is = 90 + 200 + 400 + 100 = 790
According to the tariff table, the first 100 of the summation will be multiplied by 0.2 the other 400 by 0.25 ...

```
Then the cost = (100 * 0.2) + (400 * 0.25) + (290 * 0.3) = 207
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a `join` and aggregation:

```
select sum(value * rate)
from readings r join
     tariffs t
     on r.id = t.id and
        r.value >= t.start_value and
        r.value < t.end_value;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  You need this based on the overall sum:

```
select sum(t.rate *
           greatest(least(sum_value, t.end_value) - greatest(sum_value, t.start_value), 0)
          )
from (select r.id, sum(value) as sum_value
      from readings r
     ) r join
     tariffs t
     on r.id = t.id
```

Comment: @MohammadBahja . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Sry it doesn't work for me after testing, but the query below works fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve it by the following query

```
select sum(case when sum_value - end_value >= 0 then (end_value - start_value) * rate when sum_value - start_value >= 0 then (sum_value - start_value) * rate  else 0 end)
from (
        select sum(value) as sum_value, tariffs.rate as rate, tariffs.end_value as 
        end_value, tariffs.start_value as start_value
        from readings
        join
        tariffs
        on readings.id = tariffs.id
        group by rate, end_value, start_value
     )
```